# Chrome, Firefox converting ":" to "-" and "_" respectively in their file save dialog

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

I am trying to save a file using [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) library which will save the file using **Chrome's** and **Firefox's** `Save As` dialog.

Ex: I have certain filename like **testing:testing1:testing2.csv**.

Now when the `Save As` dialog pops up, I am seeing filename converted to

`testing-testing1-testing2.csv` for **Chrome**

and

`testing_testing1_testing2.csv` for **Firefox**.

Is there any way we can suppress this conversion of characters?

Thanks

Comment: Most operating system's don't allow `:` as part of the file names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

File names can't contain, among other characters, the colon <kbd>:</kbd> (On Windows machines). If you want to make sure your application is compatible with Windows, keep that in mind.

These are the disallowed characters:

**<kbd>\</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>?</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>|</kbd>**

Firefox & Chrome probably replace all of those by the dash / underscore.

Comment: On unix at least. Look at reserved characters column [in this chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations).

Comment: Hmm... So its better to use different character instead of `:` so it will be consistent on all platforms. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The filename is merely a *suggestion*. [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html) states that:

> **19.5.1 Content-Disposition**
>
> The Content-Disposition response-header field has been proposed as a
>   means for the origin server to suggest a default filename if the user
>   requests that the content is saved to a file. This usage is derived
>   from the definition of Content-Disposition in RFC 1806 [35].

[RFC 1806](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1806.txt) further states that:

> It is important that the receiving MUA not blindly use the suggested
>   filename. The suggested filename SHOULD be checked (and possibly
>   changed) to see that it conforms to local filesystem conventions, does
>   not overwrite an existing file, and does not present a security
>   problem (see Security Considerations below).

Long story short, [different file systems have different restrictions on filenames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations). The browser is free to *fix* the filename if it cannot be used as-is.